# How to use case_when function? My output is NA's in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame with senior clients all over the age of 50.

seniorsdata

```
Name      X_Age 
Mike       55
July       64
Fay        76
Martin     93
Zack       54
Jenny      83
Suzy       56
```

This is my desired output

```
Name      X_Age    Cohort
Mike       55       50-59
July       64       60-69
Fay        76       70-79
Martin     93       90+
Zack       54       50-59
Jenny      83       80-89
Suzy       56       50-59
```

Im trying to use case when command and mutate but for some reason, the Cohort column is all NA's

```
a <- seniorsdata %>% mutate(Cohort = case_when(X_Age <= 50 & X_Age > 60 ~ '50-59',
                                          X_Age <= 60 & X_Age > 70 ~ '60-69',
                                          X_Age <= 70 & X_Age > 80 ~ '70-79',
                                          X_Age <= 80 & X_Age > 90 ~ '80-89',
                                          X_Age <= 90 & X_Age > 999 ~ '90+'
))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of using `case_when` you may want to use `cut` function

Comment: Your inequalities seem to be the wrong way. I think you want something more like `X_Age >= 50 & X_Age < 60`. Because right now your criteria don't match. There is no age that's both less than 50 and greater than 60 at the same time.

Comment: **All** your conditions are wrong. How can `X_Age` be less than or equal to 50 and greater than 60?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you specified the condition is not ideal. Please see the following.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(Cohort = case_when(
    X_Age >= 50 & X_Age < 60 ~ '50-59',
    X_Age >= 60 & X_Age < 70 ~ '60-69',
    X_Age >= 70 & X_Age < 80 ~ '70-79',
    X_Age >= 80 & X_Age < 90 ~ '80-89',
    X_Age >= 90              ~ '90+',
    TRUE                     ~ NA_character_
  ))
dat2
#     Name X_Age Cohort
# 1   Mike    55  50-59
# 2   July    64  60-69
# 3    Fay    76  70-79
# 4 Martin    93    90+
# 5   Zack    54  50-59
# 6  Jenny    83  80-89
# 7   Suzy    56  50-59
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Name      X_Age 
Mike       55
July       64
Fay        76
Martin     93
Zack       54
Jenny      83
Suzy       56",
                header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I realized what I was doing wrong. I appreciate it!